# twisted dns doesn't work

Tags: python, twisted

I'd like to know why the following doesn't work.

```
from twisted internet import defer, reactor
from twisted.python.failure import Failure
import twisted.names.client

def do_lookup(do_lookup):
    d = twisted.names.client.getHostByName(domain)
    d.addBoth(lookup_done)

def lookup_done(result):
    print 'result:', result
    reactor.stop()

domain = 'twistedmatrix.com'    
reactor.callLater(0, do_lookup, domain) 
reactor.run()
```

Results in:

```
result: [Failure instance: Traceback
(failure with no frames): <class
'twisted.names.error.ResolverError'>:
Stuck at response without answers or
delegation ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correcting your example to the following, so that it is syntactically valid:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
import twisted.names.client

def do_lookup(domain):
    d = twisted.names.client.getHostByName(domain)
    d.addBoth(lookup_done)

def lookup_done(result):
    print 'result:', result
    reactor.stop()

domain = 'twistedmatrix.com'
reactor.callLater(0, do_lookup, domain)
reactor.run()
```

I get:

```
$ python so-example.py 
result: 66.35.39.65
```

So, to answer your question: your local DNS environment is broken, not twisted.names.  Or maybe there's a bug.  You'll need to track it down further.

Comment: it works in linux. but doesn't work in windows. I get the above error. Is it looking for resolv.conf in windows?

Comment: I am working using Twisted DNS on windows and ran into the exact same issue. Did you ever work out how to fix the issue on Windows? Thanks!

Comment: How many different Windows environments have you tried this in?  What versions, etc?

Comment: @Glyph: doesn't work on Windows 7 (64bit), python 2.7.2, twisted 13.0 at least

Answer (score 5):

As of this writing, this fails on Windows, since it uses an invalid path for the windows host file (in [twisted.names.client.createResolver](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-13.0.0/twisted/names/client.py#L512).  It uses 'c:\windows\hosts'.  This was fine for windows versions 98 and Me (reference [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29)), but would fail with a version as "modern" as XP.

Today, it should probably use something like:

```
hosts = os.path.join(
                     os.environ.get('systemroot','C:\\Windows'),
                     r'system32\drivers\etc\hosts'
                    )
```

I *think* this only partly resolves the issue though (or maybe this is a red herring).

This will only work now for names actually specified in this hosts file.  What it likely needs to do is some sort of registry query for the DNS server, then query that for the actual DNS name lookup.

[This](http://en.sharejs.com/python/14533)  recipe looks promising for getting the actual DNS server.

Comment: Sounds like this should be a bug against Twisted if it's finding the hosts file incorrectly but could be doing so correctly.

Comment: Are these paths case-sensitive? Is it the same [`%WinDir%\System32\Drivers\Etc\hosts`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972034)?

Comment: Windows paths are not case sensitive.  Yes, it's the same path.  I've wavered over which is `better` to use...still not sure.  `windir` existed before `systemroot`, so if one were using windows 95, `systemroot` wouldn't exist.  I can't find a definitive answer anywhere over which to use (but would be happy for a link to something *official* on the subject)

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging why an explicit `client.createResolver(servers)` wasn't working on our corporate windows machines. In the [guts of](https://github.com/racker/python-twisted-names/blob/master/twisted/names/client.py#L551) Twisted's `createResolver` is a os-dependant branch:

```
def createResolver(servers=None, resolvconf=None, hosts=None):
    ...
    from twisted.names import resolve, cache, root, hosts as hostsModule
    if platform.getType() == 'posix':
        if resolvconf is None:
            resolvconf = '/etc/resolv.conf'
        if hosts is None:
            hosts = '/etc/hosts'
        theResolver = Resolver(resolvconf, servers)
        hostResolver = hostsModule.Resolver(hosts)
    else:
        if hosts is None:
            hosts = r'c:\windows\hosts'
        from twisted.internet import reactor
        bootstrap = _ThreadedResolverImpl(reactor)
        hostResolver = hostsModule.Resolver(hosts)
        theResolver = root.bootstrap(bootstrap)

    L = [hostResolver, cache.CacheResolver(), theResolver]
    return resolve.ResolverChain(L)
```

The first warning sign for Windows is that argument `servers` is not used, so custom-DNS servers are ignored. Next is that the _ThreadedResolverImpl(), which uses platform specific code, is wrapped in a `root.bootstrap()` before being added to the resolver chain.

The purpose of root.bootstrap is to use the platform resolver to lookup a.root-servers.net, b.root-servers.net, etc. using the synchronous Windows platform resolver (which works - and returns IPs), and then do direct DNS queries against the *root* servers. The UDP packets fired off to root servers are then blocked by our corporate firewall - I see them in Wireshark.

The default getResolver() call used by names.client.getHostByName() invokes `createResolver()` directly, which may again result in this broken setup bootstrapped by a working DNS setup. For most environments I think adding the Resolver (with root or explicit servers) into the ResolverChain along with `_ThreadedResolverImpl` as a fallback would work - except that the platform resolver is a different interface.

Here's an example of detecting the local DNS servers asynchronously (by parsing the output of `ipconfig`) then installing a custom resolver to use them.

```
import sys

from twisted.python import log
from twisted.names import root, hosts, resolve, cache, client
from twisted.python.runtime import platform

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import utils
import re

def parseIpconfigDNSServers(output):
    servers = []
    found = False
    for line in output.split('\n'):
        if 'DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . :' in line or (found and not '. . . .' in line):
            servers.append(line[38:].strip())
            found = True
        else:
            found = False
    log.msg( 'Windows: Detected DNS servers %s' % (str(servers)))
    return servers

if platform.getType() != 'posix':
    d = utils.getProcessOutput(os.path.join(os.environ['WINDIR'], 'system32', 'ipconfig.exe'), ["/all"])
    d.addCallback(parseIpconfigDNSServers)
    d.addCallback(lambda r: client.Resolver(servers=[(h, 53) for h in r]))
    d.addErrback(log.msg)
    theResolver = root.DeferredResolver(d)
    client.theResolver = resolve.ResolverChain([cache.CacheResolver(), theResolver])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
    def do_lookup(domain):
        d = client.getHostByName(domain)
        d.addBoth(log.msg)

    from twisted.internet import reactor
    reactor.callLater(0, do_lookup, 'example.com')
    reactor.run()
```

I've tidied this up and posted it here https://gist.github.com/shuckc/af7490e1c4a2652ca740

Comment: @Glyph do you think this would ever be taken upstream if submitted?