# example for twisted dns python

Tags: python

can anyone provide dns client examples for twisted except the one given in twisted source files?
I found most of examples are dns servers.

Comment: Related example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065551/twisted-dns-doesnt-work

Comment: Also, let us know what you're trying to accomplish, what you have already written, what of it works and what of it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Four years ago, I wrote [oftcdns](http://trac.oftc.net/projects/oftc-tools/browser/trunk/oftcdns), a load-balancing DNS server using python twsited. In particular, I think you'll want to review the MyAuthority class in [oftcdns.tac](http://trac.oftc.net/projects/oftc-tools/browser/trunk/oftcdns/oftcdns/oftcdns.tac). Hope this helps.